# Need Help in dealing with EXTJS in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-applications, extjs

i am very new in webdevelopment , i want to use ExtJs , please help me , i download the extjs-4.0.1 .now please tell me how to import it in my project , i mean is i copy this extjs-4.0.1 to my project or is there is another way to import it , 2nd question is where to place JS code in head section or in body section , please help me and if you have enough time then show me some sample code ,so that i can start my work on it .

Best Regards

M.Waqas Aslam

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in this site:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/

you can see there examples and documentation.

if you have a specific question return here.